# android EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android, java-io, android-permissions

I am having trouble in writing the file to sd card. (I am using Android 5.1 sdk version 23).

I have even tried the following code which prompts the user to select the user, where I select the "Sd card" and persist the permissions. 
Manifest also has the write permission.

AndroidManifest.xml

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> ```

```
public writeToFile() {
            String filePath = "/storage/sdcard1/FileBrowser/Music";
            File file = new File(filePath);
            File parentDir = file.getParentFile();
            if (parentDir != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, parentDir.toString());
                Log.d(TAG, file.getName());
                File newFile = new File(parentDir + "/test.txt");
                try {
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newFile));
                    writer.write("Hello", 0, "Hello".length());
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Parent file is null");
            }
   }


private void takeWritePermission() {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 19) {
            List<UriPermission> permissionList = getActivity().getContentResolver().getPersistedUriPermissions();
            if (permissionList != null) {
                UriPermission permission = permissionList.get(0);
                if (permission == null) {
                    startPermissionActivity();
                } else {
                    if (permission.isWritePermission()) {
                        writeToFile();
                    } else {
                        startPermissionActivity();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                startPermissionActivity();
            }
        }
    }

private void startPermissionActivity() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 42);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 19) {
            if (resultCode == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri treeUri = resultData.getData();
                getActivity().getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(treeUri,
                        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                writeToFile();
            }
        }
    }
```

> ```
> > Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> > /storage/sdcard1/FileBrowser/Music/test.txt: open failed: EACCES
> > (Permission denied)  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456) 
> > at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)  at
> > java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)  at
> > java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:42)
> ```

Comment: Its not able to find the file "test.txt" . Can you check the path again

Comment: That is the target file, which should be created for writing. It does not exist yet.

Comment: Then I guess the file is not being written properly. Can you add a debug point inside the catch block of the writeToFile methodand check if you are getting any exception.

Comment: Stack trace is printed in the catch block.

Comment: ok so that means the writing process is not happening correctly. Please post the stacktrace and check where exactly it is going wrong

Comment: can you tell the value printed for Log.d(TAG, parentDir.toString());
 and Log.d(TAG, file.getName());